# Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to study passing arguments into a function via stack in assembly. I am using fedora 20, a 64-bit system.

when I try the following code,

```
pushl %ebp

popl %ebp
```

I get the error,
`` Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push' ``

how will I overcome this error!

i compiled it by,
as -ggstabs -o Function_Stack.o Function_Stack.c

Comment: In x64 bit machine, I used ```push``` instead of ```pushl```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The error you're getting comes out from a very simple fact : the `push` instruction in 32-bit mode accepts 16-bit and 32-bit immediates as arguments. However, the `push` instruction used in 64-bit mode accepts only 16-bit and 64-bit immediates. Since you're clearly compiling your code as 64-bit, the assembler throws an error, since it cannot possibly encode such an instruction. Also, do keep in mind that you force the operand size yourself by adding the `l` suffix to the `push` instruction. Everything I just wrote here is exactly the same for `pop`, except that it accepts registers/memory, not immediates.

However, you also **need** to keep in mind the differences in the ABI between 32-bit and 64-bit Linux systems. The ABI specifies, among other things, how parameters are passed to functions, and how to call the kernel from user-mode applications. Your code is clearly written for 32-bit mode, seeing how it uses the stack for passing arguments and the (very) obsolete `int $0x80` way of invoking syscalls. In order to learn about the 64-bit ABI, see [this document](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).

Alternatively, you have the option of compiling 32-bit code on a 64-bit system. Such an executable will work if you have the necessary 32-bit runtime libraries installed on your 64-bit system. Most distributions allow you to do that in different ways. Your compiler, `as`, has the `--32` switch for emitting 32-bit code.

Comment: I used --32 switch and it created obj successfully. Now it throws error for ld prog.0 -o prog ,ld: i386 architecture of input file `prog.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output. What should be that flag for ld?

Comment: (just for reference) try using the "-melf_i386"-flag for ld.

Comment: That works fine, but then I get "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" Guess I can't run it then? =S

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419857/accessing-a-corrupted-shared-library

Comment: In 64-bit mode, push *operand-size* is 16 or 64 (pushw or pushq).  But the *immediate* width is either sign-extended-8-bit or sign-extended-32-bit.  (Or 16-bit for `pushw` with an immediate that doesn't fit in imm8.) The assembler will pick the immediate encoding for you for an instruction like `push $123`.  See also [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993).  As you say, the `l` suffix is setting the operand-size, not the immediate width like NASM `push strict dword 1`

Comment: @Ray: `exec format error` sounds like you have a kernel that was compiled without COMPAT_IA32_EMULATION, perhaps WSL1, so it can't execute 32-bit binaries.  You can of course use `ld` on such a system to make a 32-bit executable, you just can't run it locally if the kernel won't handle it.  (Such kernels also won't accept `int $0x80` system calls from 64-bit code.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  So use native 64-bit code and interfaces, or use a different kernel.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You're probably right; I don't remember which system I used exactly. Probably some zorin or elementary OS but definitely 64-bit, not sure if they include(d) x86 compatibility.